# Android Studio 1.1.0 on OSX Yosemite

Tags: android, android-studio

It's just me or when using Android Studio string resource editor, anytime I try to add a resource string Android Studio taggify the content of the string resource, this is what I mean:

```
<string name="disconnected"><Connected><to><device></device></to></Connected></string>
```

I was searching through the issues on Android Studio but I can't find anything like this reported!

Comment: you want to have a content in angular brackets?

Comment: No, Android Studio Editor automatically adds the angular brackets every time I add a word!